# Determine a function $h(x)$ that lies exactly in the middle of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functions, area

Given are two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which enclose a surface in the interval $[a,b]$. We are looking for the center and the radius of the largest possible circle within this area.

[image]

Unfortunately, the function $h(x) = (f(x) + g(x))/2$ for possible midpoints is not the correct answer, see the picture:

[image]

Please don't let the symmetry confuse you now though. I couldn't think of a better example. It's really quite general about two function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ enclosing a surface. For example, you could also search for the largest circle in the following area:

[image]

I had calculated a normal-char of one function and then simply calculated intersections with the other function. Finally, I had defined the center of these lines as a function. However, this was then a complete mess. But I can't think of anything better right now.

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly the middle" for more general functions? In this case, $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ actually have a line of symmetry. Are you assuming such a line of symmetry exists? If not, what do you want in the case that $f$ and $g$ _don't_ enclose a symmetric region?

Comment: I simply used functions as an example where I know of a symmetry. I mean by the center exactly what you see in the picture: A function whose points map the middle of two functions. Here is another picture: https://imgur.com/a/wp6jJsF

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "middle." $(f+g)/2$ would be in the "middle" (equidistant vertically from $f$ and $g$), but your example is not that. Your example looks at a function and its inverse, which are, of course, symmetric about $y=x$.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to describe it another way: I want to paint a circle between two functions. This circle should be as large as possible. Therefore, I need points that describe the centers of possible circles. These are for me "points of the center". Difficult to explain.

Comment: @Physics Do you want to paint the largest circle corresponding to every $x$ coordinate, or do you just want to draw one circle, as large as possible?

Comment: @user56202 for every $x$ coordinate

Comment: It seems to me that the biggest circle is characterized by its upper hemisphere being tangent to the top function, and its lower hemisphere being tangent to the lower function, and it seems very doable to prove this.

Comment: If this is the case, then I think you could set up a system of equations to solve your problem. I'm not sure if you can solve it for arbitrary $f, g$, but you may be able to solve it for particular ones.